# Routines and Stored procedures in JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

Am I writing this code correctly?

```sql
select sbcm_ref.process_legal_entities_buf_record(legal_entities_buf_id value from table legal_entities_buf)
```

to

```java
DSL.using(connection)
.select(Routines.processLegalEntitiesBufRecord(field(select(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF.LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF_ID)
.from(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF)))).fetch();
```

Comment: or execute() instead of fetch()?

Comment: Can you please clarify your SQL syntax? There's no `<column> value from table <table>` syntax as far as I know? What SQL query are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: First step - we did insert into LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF table. Second step - Process data using procedure: select sbcm_ref.process_legal_entities_buf_record(legal_entities_buf_id value from table legal_entities_buf) Then the procedure for creating a legal entity begins

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen any `(<column> value from table <table>)` syntax in SQL (as in your function argument list), so I'm assuming this is just some pseudo SQL you wrote, not actual SQL, or a typo?

The actual SQL would look like this, then?

```sql
select sbcm_ref.process_legal_entities_buf_record(legal_entities_buf_id)
from legal_entities_buf
```

In that case, that would translate 1:1 to jOOQ

```java
ctx.select(Routines.processLegalEntitiesBufRecord(
               LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF.LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF_ID))
   .from(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF)
   .fetch();
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: In a function argument list? ... I get it, the OP probably just placed the closing `)` at the wrong place...

Comment: Ah, I misread the query.

Comment: I have to write a query with LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF_ID value

Comment: @OleksiiHlovatskyi: I will update my answer once you update your question.  As it is now, your question isn't really very clear. The SQL you posted isn't valid, so I don't know what translation to jOOQ you're expecting. Please read this useful resource about what people trying to answer your question might be expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's what I need:
DSL.using(connection)
                .select(Routines.processLegalEntitiesBufRecord(field(select(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF.LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF_ID)
                        .from(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF)                        .where(LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF.LEGAL_ENTITIES_BUF_ID.eq(legalEntityId)))))
                .fetch();

Comment: @OleksiiHlovatskyi: OK, then what's your problem? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: No more problems! The code works! Thank you!

Comment: @LukasEder: I am using JOOQ for genetation data for automated tests. I have a lot of tasks. I will sometimes ask you to help me) Have a nice day!

Comment: @OleksiiHlovatskyi: No problem. I'm looking at all the questions here on Stack Overflow